# Открытие файла через стороннюю программу

Tags: c#, файлы

Как запустить/открыть файл с помощью программы, которая не ассоциируется в винде с данным типом файлов?

Например, есть файл main.html, его нужно открыть в блокноте, а не в браузере.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad.exe main.html");
```